# xpath expression descendant confusion

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
<xsl: when test="not(descendant::*[SomeAttribute])">
```

Does this mean to check if a context node does NOT have a descendant with a child element `SomeAttribute` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Since a node set as boolean is false if the set is empty and true if it is not, the effect is that the test will fail if the context node has a `SomeAttribute` descendant at least two levels down the tree (grandchild, great-grandchild, etc.).  If the context node has `SomeAttribute` *children* but not deeper descendants, or has no `SomeAttribute` descendants at all, then the test will succeed.